# Request Clarification of Django Model Choice Code from Docs

Tags: django, choicefield

In the official docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices we are given this example:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                      choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                                      default=FRESHMAN)
```

What is the purpose of setting the variables to strings before, and in addition to, the actual tuples of `YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES`? 
Where are those strings used? 
Are these variables then the same ones used in the tuple?
If so, why? That seems like an additional and unnecessary step.

It does not help that in the example immediately before this one, they use *different* `YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES`. Thanks for clarifying.

UPDATE

Since I am sitting here wrestling with this code as we speak, thanks to all for the quick responses. They all add something to my understanding. I think @shang-wang has the most concise and responsive answer to my question so far. 1+ for the reference to get_FOO_display(). But in my particular use case, the choices are for the admin to tell the end user how a particular object has been evaluated. So I want the 'human-readable' form of the evaluations to be what displays in the final html template to the end user on the site. In light of these answers, now I'm wondering if this is the best way to achieve my goal? Is the solution :

`

> html display table

Name of object   |    Evaluation

FOO                   |     foo.get_evaluation_display()

> or maybe:

for FOO in objects:
Name of object   |    Evaluation
FOO.name             |    foo.get_evaluation_display()
'

The purpose of this particular model is to display expert evaluations of FOO to end users. Each FOO can have many such evaluations. Although usually quite verbose, these evaluations can be categorized, hence the choice field. Users can then click over to read the original evaluation in full if they want.  So FOO is defined on a different model, and is linked to the evaluation model by a foreign key. So will get_FOO_display() actually work here, since the choice field isn't on the model where FOO is an instance?

p.s, I realize this has now become a different question, so if it needs to be moved or whatever, I'm ok with that, but it does come directly from the original q&a. Let me know. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES` is served as all possible choices in the field `year_in_school`. The first value in each pair in `YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES` is the one that will be stored in database, while the second value in each pair is the one that will show up in your form dropdown(if you use the default widget). The individual selection declaration like `FRESHMAN = 'FR'` is to make sure that they are encapsulated in the class. You can do the following for each student object:

```
# assign the value to student's year_in_school
student.year_in_school = Student.FRESHMAN
student.save()

# this will print 'FR'
db_value = student.year_in_school
print db_value

# this will print 'Freshman'
pretty_display_value = student.get_year_in_school_display()
print pretty_display_value
```

Django doc for [get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems to explain the reasoning in the paragraph after the example

> Though you can define a choices list outside of a model class and then
>   refer to it, defining the choices and names for each choice inside the
>   model class keeps all of that information with the class that uses it,
>   and makes the choices easy to reference (e.g, `Student.SOPHOMORE` will
>   work anywhere that the Student model has been imported).

It seems they suggest it's a good idea the make the options class variable so you will never have to refer to the raw val (e.g. `'FR'`). It's also to make sure you have access to these variable everywhere you import this model.

Answer (score 1):

```
# within your models.Model class...
STUDENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
)
year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                  choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                                  default=FRESHMAN)




This means elsewhere in your code if you want to specify a choice field value, you’d have to enter the first slot of the tuple’s value, e.g.:

year_in_school = models.objects.filter(year_in_school_type='SOPHOMORE') 


**This is pretty terrible** since it’s hardcoded in our source, possibly over many files.
```

To avoid this use below as class:
     pip install **enum34**
     import inspect
from enum import Enum

```
class ChoiceEnum(Enum):

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        # get all members of the class
        members = inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda m: not(inspect.isroutine(m)))
        # filter down to just properties
        props = [m for m in members if not(m[0][:2] == '__')]
        # format into django choice tuple
        choices = tuple([(str(p[1].value), p[0]) for p in props])
        return choices


**That’s the hard work over.**

Now  you create your choice field:

from common.utils import ChoiceEnum

class StudentTypes(ChoiceEnum):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'

# within your models.Model class...
year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=StudentTypes.choices())


Now if we need to access StudentTypes from elsewhere in our source code, we can simply:

# import StudentTypes
year_in_school =  models.objects.filter(year_in_school=StudentTypes.junior.value)
```